# Digamos vs dígamos. ¿Cuál es correcto?

Tags: conjugación, acentuación

Dígamos o digamos. ¿Cuál es correcto en cuál region o en cuál contexto?

Según esta tabla de conjugaciones debe ser «digamos»:

https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/decir

Pero hay muchos resultados para «dígamos» también.

Aquí hay un ejemplo:
https://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias/2016/02/160208_blog_lalo_leicester_city_sensacion_vardy_mahrez_premier_league_jmp

> Dígamos, para no extendernos demasiado, que ahora tiene unos 340.000
>   habitantes...

¿Se trata de un error tipográfico?

Comment: "Dígamos" es [portugués](https://dicionario.priberam.org/d%C3%ADgamo).

Comment: Gracias, Charo. Entiendo, pero hay mucho contenido en español tambien usando «dígamos». Se trata de un error typográfico?

Comment: A parte de cosas como [esta](https://dle.rae.es/b%C3%ADgamo), no creo que aparezca en páginas fiables. Por cierto, es "tipográfico".

Comment: Gracias, Charo. Añadí un ejemplo que encontré.

Comment: Sin lugar a dudas se trata de un error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

«Digamos» es una palabra grave, y al terminar en s, no se pone la tilde en la vocal acentuada, por tanto la palabra que buscas es:

> Digamos

Puedes confirmarlo [acá](https://dle.rae.es/decir#conjugaciondpfyJHi), viendo la primera persona del plural en el presente subjuntivo de «decir».

<s>*Dígamos*</s> no existe y es un error tipográfico en el texto que citas.

Answer (score -1):

Todo depende de dónde esté la sílaba tónica. Dependiendo de dónde esté, llevará o no tile.

Están las palabras **agudas** que la sílaba tónica (donde tiene más fuerza la sílaba) está en la última sílaba. Llevan tilde cuando la palabra termina en *n*, *s* o *vocal*.

Por ejemplo: Ra-**tón**, pro-tec-**tor**, em-pren-de-**dor**, ru-**bí**, etc.

Están las palabras **llanas** que la sílaba tónica está en la penúltima posición. Todas las que no terminen en *n*, *s* o *vocal*, llevarán tilde.

Por ejemplo: **ár**-bol, **lá**-piz, por-**tá**-til, **me**-sa, **si**-lla, etc.

También están las palabras **esdrújulas** las cuales todas llevan tilde cuando la sílaba tónica está en la antepenúltima posición.

Por ejemplo: **úl**-ti-mo, **nú**-me-ro, **rá**-pi-do, **lá**-gri-ma, etc.

Digamos, al ser una palabra llana y termina en *s*, no llevaría tilde. Puedes verlo en el [Diccionario de la Real Academia Española](https://dle.rae.es/decir?m=form#conjugaciondpfyJHi).

Comment: La explicación es muy precisa, pero sospecho que dígamos no existe, o dicho de otra manera, es un error ortográfico, ya que no pertenece a ninguna conjugación o tiempo verbal

Comment: En la pregunta especifíco cuál sería el uso correcto del verbo decir. Como dije, sin tilde al ser llana. Se sobreentiende que, si no menciono la otra, es que es incorrecta ortográficamente.

Comment: hacía vs hacia, ambas creo que existen, y hay algunas conjugaciones donde existen ambas formas, con o sin tilde, este no es el caso

Comment: Primero, hacia no es una conjugación, es una preposición, y hacía es el pretérito imperfecto del verbo hacer. "Hacia" no lleva tilde porque la sílaba tónica esta en la penúltima posición, mientras que hacía es aguda. No dejan de ser palabras distintas con la sílaba tónica en posiciones distintas. Dígamos no existe.